# How to Change the code from For Loops to FoldLeft,Fold or FoldRight on Data frames in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to Compare two datasets(DS1 and DS2). So, I got them pulled into two dataframes and now I want to compare each and every Column of (DS1) with each and every Column of DS2.
Before comparing each and every record from each column, I would like to reduce my data by performing GroupBy, so I can decrease the number of records to compare.
I will pass this records to compare from both datasets to my Algorithm which will return a score back.
I did it using **for loops**, the results are good, but it is taking a lot of time.
Below is my code using 4 nested for Loops,

```
// StringDS1 and StringDS2 are Dataframes
var s1= stringDS1.columns
var s2= stringDS2.columns
var contentString = ofDim[Double](s1.size,s2.size)
var ds1StringCount = stringDS1.count()
var ds2StringCount = stringDS2.count()
for (i <- 0 to s1.size-1) {
  println("entered 1st for Loop")
  var ds1s =stringDS1.groupBy(s1(i)).count() // GroupBy of every column before comparing on DS1
  ds1s.show()
  for(j <- 0 to s2.size-1) {
    var totalScore:Double=0
    println("entered 2nd for loop")
    var ds2s = stringDS2.groupBy(s2(j)).count() //GroupBy of every column before comparing on DS1
    ds2s.show()
    var score = new Array[Double](ds2s.count().toInt)
    var maxScore = new Array[Double](ds1s.count().toInt)
    var m:Int=0
    for(row <- ds1s.rdd.collect()) {

      println("entered 3rd for loop")
      var key1 = row(0).toString
      var value1 = row(1).toString
      println("Key1 is " + key1 + " value is " + value1)
      var s = 0 //Score Array iterator
      for (row <- ds2s.rdd.collect()) {
        println("entered 4th for loop")

        var key2 = row(0).toString
        var value2 = row(1).toString
        println(" key2 is " + key2 + "value 2 is " + value2)
        //println(ds1StringCount + " " + ds2StringCount)
        println("size is " + score.size)
        score(s) = contentAlgoString(key1, key2, value1, value2)  // ContentAlgoString is the Method for the Algorithm where it
                                              // returns a score and that score is stored in an array
        s = s + 1
      } // Loop for k1 -> k2

      maxScore(m) = score.max        // maxScore(m) is an array that stores the max value from the Score Array
      println("Max Score is " + maxScore(m))
      totalScore = totalScore + (maxScore(m) * (value1.toDouble / ds1StringCount.toDouble))
      println("Total Score is " + totalScore)
      m = m + 1


    } // loop for all k1's -> all k2's

    contentString(i)(j)= totalScore  // Total Score is stored in this Array
  }
}
```

By removing "**FOR Loops**" and using "**Foldleft**" instead can I optimize my code and retrieve faster results.
Is there any other approach other than folds to improve my results or get faster results.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a "please do it for me" sort of question. In your case `map` looks more sutable than `fold`: `s2.map(col => ...)` . And don't expect a speedup from such a refactoring.

Comment: I'm new to this actually. I'm a student and trying to finish a Project ASAP. Is there any guide or blog you can refer me to learn map, how I can iterate through all the Columns and records. Thanks

Comment: If you have to finish it ASAP - just stick with techniques you already familiar with.

Comment: If you wish to learn it - you have to invest some time into reading a book or take an online course https://www.coursera.org/specializations/scala

Comment: Thanks, I will enroll in the course